# git - files checked in Branch-1, showing up in Branch-2

Tags: git

Here is the scenario :

I've 2 branches created - b1, b2 for 2 commits 
Both the branches have different files changed & committed

When I commit files into b1, the 2 files specific to b1 get committed

Checking in files to Branch-b1

```
git checkout -b "Branch-b1"
git add /path/file1.scala
git add /path/file2.scala
git commit -m "<Comment>"
git push -u origin "Branch-b1"
```

However, when I create b2 & commit the 6 files specific to b2, 6 + 5 files are getting committed

Checking in files to Branch-b2

```
git checkout -b "Branch-b2"
git add /path/file3.scala
git add /path/file4.scala
git commit -m "<Comment>"
git push -u origin "Branch-b2"
```

In the second case, what is getting checked in is - files fro Branch-b1 + files from Branch-b2

In fact, when I create a new branch (eg b3) and do not commit any files, & I do a diff between the 
branch b3 & master . I see the files checked in for branch b1

eg.

```
git checkout -b "Branch-b3"

git diff Branch-b3 master
--- shows the files from Branch-b1
/path/file1.scala
/path/file2.scala
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
And how to fix this?

Comment: what is your aim? If you committed files on branch 1 and THEN do `git checkout -b Branch-b2` then branch 2 will contain everything that was in the branch 1, this is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `Branch-b2` *on top of* `Branch-b1` (and from your description probably `Branch-b3` as well). Therefore, each branch will contain all files from its predecessor(s).

`git checkout -b` is a shortcut for [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), followed by [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) (i.e. you create a new branch and immediately switch to it). `git branch` on the other hand will create a new branch *on top of your current HEAD*, which is the tip of the branch you are currently on.

You need to switch back to `master` before creating a new branch using `git checkout -b`.